# In Microsoft Word, how do I change the order of items in an enumerated list without breaking cross references?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

In a Microsoft-Word document, I have an enumerated list and several cross references to list items. Example ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1hD.png)):

```
 (1) Foo
 (2) Bar
 (3) Fred

References: Foo is (1), Bar is (2), Fred is (3).
```

I want to change the order of the items and have the references updated. Example:

```
 (1) Fred
 (2) Foo
 (3) Bar

References: Foo is (2), Bar is (3), Fred is (1).
```

How do I do this? All the copying-and-pasting or selecting-and-dragging that I tried has resulted in broken or (even worse) wrong cross references. For example, if I select the line containing the Fred entry and drag it to the beginning of the list, the list is changed as expected, but the cross refereces become (after updating):

```
References: Foo is (1), Bar is (3), Fred is (1).
```

Word Version is 2013, but I imagine that this issue also applies to other versions of Word.

Comment: @Thimo Demey: Please do not *replace* text with an image.

Comment: @Run5K: Please do not approve edits that replace text with a picture.

Comment: When you cut and paste, make sure you press Enter at end of paragraph where you want to move entry to (instead of pressing Enter at start of paragraph).  Example, cut Fred paragraph (including its paragraph marker), don't put cursor at start of Foo - instead go to end of paragraph above that and press Enter there to create new paragraph and paste your Fred paragraph, then delete the extra blank paragraph.  When you refresh, your xrefs should update correctly.

Comment: @Tanya Inserting a new paragraph above the list (rather than pasting the cut entry at the beginning of the list) works. Would you be so kind to convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cut and paste, make sure you press Enter at end of paragraph where you want to move entry to (instead of pressing Enter at start of paragraph). Example, cut Fred paragraph (including its paragraph marker), don't put cursor at start of Foo - instead go to end of paragraph above that and press Enter there to create new paragraph and paste your Fred paragraph, then delete the extra blank paragraph. When you refresh, your xrefs should update correctly. –